# Apple pay from Braintree

Tags: braintree, applepay

I use apple pay via Braintree, and I got a error when I created a sale. The error code is 91577(Payment instrument not supported by merchant account).

Answer (score 1):

<sub>I work at Braintree. For questions like this that are very specific to the Braintree platform, your best bet is to [get in touch with our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

This error means your merchant account is not set up to accept Apple Pay. If this happens you need to [contact Braintree support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) with the details of how to trigger the problem and your account info.